# using xstream with mysql

Tags: java, database, xstream

I am trying to use xStream and get mysql values to *.xml files. But when I try this with the code below, it just writes the first object to an xml file and then doesn't add anything other than the first object. Is it a problem about using xstream.toXML or something else?

```
 ResultSet kayit = st.executeQuery("select * from otel");
 XStream xstream = new XStream();
 FileWriter xmlFile = new FileWriter("D:\\OTEL.xml");
 while (kayit.next()) {
  Oteldata o = new Oteldata();
  o.name = kayit.getString("otelisim");
  o.room = kayit.getString("oteloda");
  o.konte = kayit.getString("otelkonte");
  String xml = xstream.toXML(o);
  xmlFile.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n");
  xmlFile.write(xml + "\n");
  xmlFile.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you start your while loop, retrieve the object, use xstream.toXML(o), and then do your writes, and close your write file. There is no closing of your write loop shown.

Try:

```
ResultSet kayit = st.executeQuery("select * from otel");
XStream xstream = new XStream();
FileWriter xmlFile = new FileWriter("D:\\OTEL.xml");
xmlFile.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n");
while (kayit.next()) {
    Oteldata o = new Oteldata();
    o.name = kayit.getString("otelisim");
    o.room = kayit.getString("oteloda");
    o.konte = kayit.getString("otelkonte");
    String xml = xstream.toXML(o);
    xmlFile.write(xml + "\n");
}
xmlFile.close();
```

Do your initial write for the first line before the loop, then do your loop writing each object, close your loop, and then close your file

Comment: 3: <isim>AHMET</isim> 
 4: <oda>100</oda> 
 5: <konte>20</konte> 
 6: </com.eun.random.p4.Oteldata> <com.eun.random.p4.Oteldata> 
 7: <isim>MAHMUT</isim> 
 8: <oda>30</oda> 
 9: <konte>10</konte>


it adds such text, which is unreadable for xml..double headtags =|